# How to make the public 2D collection?

Tags: c#, collections

I want to create the public 2D collection, but don't know how.

```
namespace AutoSqare
{
    class CarsInfo
    {
        public class Tech
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double KM { get; set; }
        }
        public var List<Tech> cars = new List<Tech>(); // error, of course
    }
}
```

Comment: The **var** in  `public var List<Tech> cars = new List<Tech>();`  shouldn't be there.

Comment: It's just a typo, you must remove var.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because your are declaring your list of cars with **var** AND **List**

**var** is used as an implicit type and allow you to not specify the type of the variable. It will be strongly typed by the compilator.

Just declare your variable **explicitely** and you'll be ok ;)

```
public List<Tech> cars = new List<Tech>();
```

Doc on var [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)